# Running through entire range of `unsigned char` in `for` loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

I would like to run through the entire range of `unsigned char` in a `for` loop. Say I want to print all numbers from 0 to 255, how should I go about accomplishing that?

The following code would be an infinite loop:

```
for (unsigned char i=0; i<=255; i++)
    cout << i << endl;
```

This one misses out on 0 or 255, depending on whether it is `i++` or `++i`

```
for (unsigned char i=0; ++i<=255; i++)
    cout << i << endl;
```

I could place a cout before/after the `for` loop to compensate for the missing entry, but I seek a more elegant solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! (`while` and `do-while` loops are also welcomed!)

Comment: Do you want C answers or C++ answers?

Comment: Probably C++, what with the stream I/O.

Comment: Just use an `int` and then cast it.

Comment: @FredLarson Either would do.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I would like a more elegant solution IF one exists.

Comment: @BlackAdder how is that not elegant?

Comment: "Say I want to print all numbers from 0 to 255" - well, considering which overloads `cout` offers, what you've written here certainly won't do that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try,

```
unsigned char i = 0 ;
do {
  cout << i << endl ;
}
while ( ++i ) ;
```

The benefit of `do .. while` over the other forms is you get one free run before the condition is tested.  This is an important tool for that reason (if only infrequently used), in a programmer's toolbox.

Comment: Because when `i` is `255` then `++i` will overflow back to 0, no?

Comment: This is how I would write it in assembly language too.

Comment: Thanks @woolstar, this answer is a beauty. I'm beginning to like programming now, no thanks to this gem.

Comment: @AlexisWilke hopefully this maps very closely to that assembly.

Comment: @BlackAdder, Careful, though. This behaviour is only well-defined for unsigned integral types. Sorry if that ruined it again.

Comment: Superb! The one thing you lose is internal scoping of the counter, but using `for` for this seems to require `for (unsigned char c = 0; c + 1 > 0; ++c)`, which is, of course, very ugly and wasteful => unlikely to optimise so well. @chris I doubt anyone evaluating things in this much detail is unaware of that caveat ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can break it up:

```
for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
    unsigned char base=i*16;
    for (unsigned char j = 0; j < 16; ++j)
    {
        unsigned char val=base+j;
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [boost::irange](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/irange.html) could be considered elegant (*[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72f2c46ca087e00d)*):

```
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for(auto i : boost::irange(0, 256) )
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```