# How to avoid infinite loop when iterating through every value of an unsigned type?

Tags: infinite-loop, pseudocode

If I want to iterate through the values `0` to `255` and I use unsigned byte as the counter, when the counter reaches `255` it goes back to `0` and makes an infinite loop.

```
for (ubyte i = 0; i < ubyte.max; i++)
    //do something with i
```

I want the same loop but without changing the type of `i` to a bigger type. And the solution should work for any unsigned int like `uint` and `ulong`.

This type of loop is a common pitfall when writing code and I need an universal solution without being too hacky or ugly.

Comment: what language is this - you had c#, c++ and c.

Comment: any C like language. pseudocode. the snippet is D code actually but it is the same in all of them

Comment: @Bosak I think the answer would be specific to a certain language. There is no generic solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running through entire range of \`unsigned char\` in \`for\` loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986423/running-through-entire-range-of-unsigned-char-in-for-loop)

Answer (score 4):

```
ubyte i = 0;
do
{
    // do something
}
while (++i != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ubyte i=0;
do {
    //do something with i
} while (++i != 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
for(ubyte j = 0;;) {
  // Do something with j
  if ( j == ubyte.max) break;
  ++j;
}
```

or:

```
for(ubyte j = 0;;++j) {
  // Do something with j
  if ( j == ubyte.max) break;
}
```

I admit that I would prefer a solution with the condition at the top, but I don't see a good one.